# Virtual function pitfalls and using base functions

Tags: c++, polymorphism, using, virtual-functions

I have been coding up a reference thing for virtual functions since I always forget some piece of how they work. Here is what I have thus far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    virtual void foo(int one = 1, int two = 2) = 0;

    virtual Base* bar() { cout << "Base bar\n"; return this; }

    virtual void baz(Base*) { cout << "Base baz\n"; }

    virtual void boo(Base*) { cout << "Base boo\n"; }

    // Error: templates may not be virtual
    //template <typename T> virtual T bad(T t) {return t}

    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void foo(int one = 3, int two = 4) 
        { cout << "one: " << one << " two: " << two << endl; }

    Derived* bar() { cout << "Derived bar\n"; return this; }

    void baz(Derived*) { cout << "Derived baz\n"; }

    using Base::boo;
    void boo(Derived*) { cout << "Derived boo\n"; }
};

void example1()
{
    Base*       pB = new Derived();
    Derived*    pD = new Derived();

    // Foo is called with default parameters based on pointer
    pB->foo();  // one: 1 two: 2
    pD->foo();  // one: 3 two: 4

    // Bar is overridden because return type can be implicitly converted
    pB->bar();  // Derived bar
    pD->bar();  // Derived bar

    // Baz is not overridden because parameters differ
    pB->baz(pB);    // Base baz
    pB->baz(pD);    // Base baz
    //pD->baz(pB);  // invalid conversion from Base* to Derived*
    pD->baz(pD);    // Derived baz

    // Boo using test
    pB->boo(pB);    // Base boo
    pB->boo(pD);    // Base boo
    pD->boo(pB);    // Base boo
    pD->boo(pD);    // Derived boo

    delete pB;
    delete pD;
}

struct Base2
{
    void foo(int one = 1, int two = 2) { foo_impl(one, two); }

    virtual ~Base2() {}

private:
    virtual void foo_impl(int one, int two) = 0;
};

struct Derived2 : public Base2
{
private:
    void foo_impl(int one, int two) 
        { cout << "one: " << one << " two: " << two << endl; }
};

void example2()
{
    Base2*       pB = new Derived2();
    Derived2*    pD = new Derived2();

    // Now one set of default parameters exists
    pB->foo();  // one: 1 two: 2
    pD->foo();  // one: 1 two: 2

    delete pB;
    delete pD;
}

int main()
{
   example1();
   example2();
   return 0;
}
```

I am confused by the boo() function. It seems to me that `pB->boo(pD)` near the end of `example1()` should call the overridden version of the function, but it calls the base version. Why? If you could explain where all `using` is needed and how it works, that would be helpful, thanks.

Also, if you can think of other pitfalls to watch for when using virtual functions, feel free to post those too. Thanks.

Comment: Currently the code has undefined behavior. The base class destructor must be virtual.

Comment: @Mahesh Added for good practice, but are you sure that makes a difference here since there are not member variables?

Comment: The standard specifies "if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined"

Comment: Why does your virtual member function argument differ in types from Base to Derived class ? If you can explain that, then we can help why you need `using` directive.

Comment: Aside: Best get into the habit of explicitly defaulting with `= default;` where you want a default ctor / dtor / op=, instead of writing them yourself. It's advantageous because doing so does not stop the class from being trivial.

Comment: Consider using [`override`](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#override).

Comment: @nwp unfortunately, I cannot use c++11. We have to be able to compile to TI chips and their compiler is waaay behind.

Comment: @Deduplicator are you saying to use `virtual ~Base() = default;`, etc.? That does make sense. I will try to work that into my habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be see by what happens with the `baz` function. As you note in your comment, the derived class's `baz` does not override the base class's version because the parameters differ. That's the same case for `boo`.

Your `using Base::boo;` statement doesn't in any way change `boo` not overriding. Instead it just brings the base version in scope for the derived class. Essentially, it's as if the derived class then has two *overloads* of the function.

However with `pB->boo(pD);` overloads aren't relevant since the pointer is typed in terms of `Base`. So the compiler only knows about the base class's `boo` function. And thus since nothing is overriding `boo` it ends up calling the base version.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. So `Base` just has the `boo(Base*)` while Derived has `boo(Base*)` and `boo(Derived*)`, so when looking up the function based on the pointer, it can only see the one. I think I got it.